# EFCore A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I got this error, but im unable to determine what is the real cause, therefore im unable to fix it? "Entity Framework Core: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed"

The context

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context) 
{
    _context = context;
}
```

The error occurs here "await _context.SaveChangesAsync();", however this statement is executed only once.

```
        //Find user by Id
        var foundUser = await _context.Users.FindAsync(myUserId);

        //Populate myUserData here
         ....

        //If user not found, create the user
        if (foundUser == null)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(myUserData);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); //<--------ERROR HERE!
        }
```

Comment: Likely unrelated, but in this pattern how is `_context` disposed?

Comment: The code above is in a method, and I was using it without "await" , I added "await" and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify foundUser , but it's not returned yer becuase it's async.

The easier way to fix this is using .Result like this:

```
if (foundUser.Result == null)
```

This way it will wait for the result of the previous call

Comment: Unless foundUser's type have a `Result` property, I think this `if (foundUser.Result == null)` won't compile